# How to remove macOS app from device during development

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm working with CoreData on macOS, and in the interests of debugging, I have to remove the app from my device.

In developing iOS, this is trivial since using a simulator I can simply delete the app. On macOS, however, the deployed app doesn't appear in my Mac Applications folder. How can I delete the app and all associated data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can locate the debug app in Xcode by selecting the menu `Product -> Show Build Folder in Finder`. This will open a Finder window with the "Build" folder selected within the DerivedData for the project. Inside the "Build" folder will be the "Products" folder then the "Debug" (or maybe "Release") folder. That will contain the actual .app.

Assuming you are building a sandboxed app, the app's sandbox (and its data) is located elsewhere. That will be found in:

> ~/Library/Containers/<app bundle id>

Inside this folder you will find lots of files representing the sandbox and any data you may have saved within the sandbox. You can delete the `<app bundle id>` folder if you want to start fresh.

If the app is granted access to folders outside of the sandbox, such as Desktop, Downloads, etc., then that data may be scattered within those folders. Clearly you do not want to delete ~/Desktop, ~/Downloads, etc.